# cd: /D: No such file or directory error message under windows 10

Tags: perl, windows-10

I wrote a perl script that runs command strings using the `system` perl command. And under Windows 10, when it comes to running a command like

```
cd /D R:/some_path…`
```

it gives the following error message

```
sh: line 0: cd: /D: No such file or directory
```

but directly running the same command via Windows 10 `cmd` is successful. What's odd to me here is that this error message is used to appear on Linux systems. what could be causing this behaviour, and how can I get it to work correctly?

Comment: The `/d` option is supported by `cmd.exe` but not `sh`. The `system` command uses `sh`.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for the explanation, Is it possible to fix it with code, or do I need to change some system settings?

Comment: You're not really using Windows; you're using some kind of unix emulation (cygwin? msys?) In unix, Perl uses `/bin/sh`. If you want to execute a `cmd` command,, you will need to run `cmd`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, for me in Strawberry Perl, running `perl -e "system('cd /d Z:/tmp');"` works fine.  Maybe Perl compiled from scratch on Windows uses a different default shell?  Vahag, it would be nice if you provide some more details about the Perl you're using and a reproducible code snippet.

Comment: @jimtut, Yes, Windows builds of Perl use `cmd` for `system SHELLCMD`. They're not using a Windows build of Perl. Doesn't stop them from using `cmd` (`system "cmd", "/c", SHELLCMD`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all the comments. I figured out that the Perl I'm using is inside the cygwin/bin folder. I changed it to regular perl under windows and it works great.

Comment: This solved my problem too. I was installing Git, which included its own distro, which did not behave as expected. Run `where perl.exe` to make sure you're running the version of Perl you expect!